# how to run angular 4 app and nodejs api on same port 4200 for both production and development?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have created angular 4 app and I can run it using `ng serve --open` and  it runs on `localhost:4200` ,
what I want is I have also created api using `nodejs` in same angular project now I want to run that API at `localhost:4200/api` so I have tried something like this

my angular 4 and nodejs srtucture look like this

```
/dist
/server
  /routes
  /server
/src
app.js
package.json
```

in app.js I used

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/app/api', apiRoutes);
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Once I run using `nodemon app.js` and go at `localhost:3000` it run my angular app and it's fine and than I go at `localhost:3000/app/api` it's also work fine and good ,

But when I change in angular app it's not auto refresh my app because it's running node app currently for refresh it I need to run `ng build` and than it will effect my new changes on angular app

So, What I want is to run `ng serve --open` it will run angular app but not node js api so want to run both and once i change in any from angular app or node js app it must be auto refresh.

Comment: Do you want to serve client and server on same port only for development or for production?

Comment: @Jarek i want to serve client and server on same port only for both development and production.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't have two different applications running on the same port. Angular-cli uses a nodejs server (technically it's webpack-dev-server) behind the scenes when you run `ng serve`, which means that port is already in use.

There are two possible solutions.

1. Use your node application to serve the static frontend files. Then you can't really use `ng serve` (this is probably what you'd do when running live).
2. Use nodejs with a different port, and use Angular's proxy config, to have Angular think the api port is actually 4200 (this is probably best during development).

This is primarily a concern during development I reckon, since you most likely wont (and shouldn't) be using `ng serve` live, so option 2 would be my best recommendation.

To configure a proxy, you create a file in your angular application root directory called `proxy.config.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Then when you run `ng serve`, you run it with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` instead.

[Here's a link to the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

---

**Here's an alternative when building for production (solution 1 above):**

To build in production you use `ng build --prod` to [create a production ready Angular build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and then (assuming you use Express on your node server), use something like `app.use(express.static('dist/'))` as explained in the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). I'm not using node myself (I'm using .NET Core) so I'm afraid I can't provide much more in terms of details.

Comment: Also write about the possibility of prerendering javascript on server side: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Comment: That's definitely something to take into account as well, thank you.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen i got Error like `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/users from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Comment: Are you running your node server as well?

Comment: Try adding `"changeOrigin": true,` to the proxy config.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen it's working on local but how will i run on server, i'm using Heroku server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154289/discussion-between-kumbhanibhavesh-and-nikolaj-dam-larsen).

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ng serve` in a production environment. The Angular-cli uses the webpack dev server behind the scenes which, as the name suggest, is meant for use during development only. When running in production, I suggest using option 1 in my answer.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen how should i do 1 answer?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen please explain me your first ans i want to do it for both production and development

Comment: The first solution can be a bit counter-productive when used in development, since you can't really use `ng serve` then. You're really best off having two different processes for development and production. I've added an explanation of how you might use solution 1 in a production environment, to the answer above.

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh you need to "ng build --prod" then put "dist" folder that generated by build command to your nodejs server app, and add this line to your nodejs app main file (app.js/index.js) : 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

Comment: for me secure was not needed, furthermore if you need to debug add   "logLevel": "debug",and you can use [::1] instead of localhost {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://[::1]:3030",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

There is one awesome blog on medium by Daniel Kagan which explain all, here the link.
[Hot deploy](https://medium.com/@danielkagan/serve-mean-stack-using-angular-cli-f39b33dbad64) its explain about client hot deployment i added some more code to make client and server hot deployment.

This answer is purely for development hot reload

**Step one.**

Install [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) and [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

npm i concurrently

npm i nodemon

You can install globally as well with -g flag

**Step Two.**

Open your servers package.json file,
and add following four line to it. **Note** i have my angular code inside client folder so i did **cd client**

```
"buildclient": "cd client && ng build",
"runclient": "cd client && npm start",
"devstart": "nodemon --inspect ./bin/www",
"dev": "npm run buildclient & concurrently --kill-others \"npm run runclient\" \"npm run devstart\""
```

If you don't want inspect node app then remove `--inspect` flag.

**Step Three.**

Go to your angular folder and create file ***proxy.conf.json*** add following line to file.

```
 {
   "/api/*": {
   "target": "http://localhost:3000",
   "secure": false,
   "changeOrigin": true
 }
 }
```

**Step Four.**

Add following command inside angular's package.json file

`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

**Step Five.**

Make angular build output directory inside public folder of server. To do this go to angular.json change build outputPath to `../public` following is JSON snippet.

```
"options": {
        "outputPath": "../public",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

**Step Six.**

Make sure your node express server app.js file read static files from public folder.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

**Step Seven.**

npm run dev

Done goto http://localhost:4200 you can see you app there :) all call to /api will get to node express server.

Any changes to server or client will be hot deployed automatically.

**NOTE** I used [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to create my server and [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) to create angular application. If you did it some other way then some files might not be present

Answer (score 1):

1.first build you angular 6 app 
  run ng build --watch

2.from nodejs app
  write this middle ware 
  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/dist/client')));`
  as the folder pointing to client/dist/client is build folder of angular 6 app.

then run nodemon --inspect app.js

make sure to have a hirearchy of folders like this

`/myproject 
   /client 
    /dist 
     /client
      /....
      /index.html
   /app.js
   /.....`

listen to the port you want to run from app.js
and run localhost:portno

hope this helps

Comment: there is nothing to give -1 on this as this is the answer to this question if you want to build your angular app with node on same port and moreover give it a public path also of your build folder and run nodemon --inspect app.js

Comment: I am with u, neutralized.