# Can I hot module reload the server (.NET Core) and client (Angular) at the same time?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I'm using **'dotnet watch run'** to watch for changes in my server code and **'ng build --watch'** to watch for changes in my Angular code. Both are rebuilding the code properly into **"bin/"** and **"wwwroot/"** respectively.

### myapp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>myapp</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- extends watching group to include *.js files -->
    <Watch Include="wwwroot\*.js;bin\**\*"/> <!-- Exclude="node_modules\**\*;**\*.js.map;obj\**\*;bin\**\*" /> -->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My **Startup.cs** is set to read from the "wwwroot" file and serve my transpiled TypeScript.

### Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;

namespace myapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                /*app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });*/
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles(); // URL rewriter to serve default web page
            app.UseStaticFiles(); // makes files in wwwroot servable
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the project with **"npm run saw"** concurrently so both watch commands can be in the same terminal. I want the client and server to run on the same port so that's why I let "dotnet run" serve the app.

### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start:client": "ng serve",
    "build:client": "ng build",
    "build:client:watch": "ng build --watch",
    "build:server": "dotnet build",
    "build:all": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:client:prod": "ng build --prod --env=prod",
    "build:all:prod": "npm run build:client:prod && npm run build:server",
    "test:client": "ng test",
    "lint:client": "ng lint",
    "e2e:client": "ng e2e",
    "restore": "dotnet restore",
    "start:all": "ng serve --live-reload false && dotnet run",
    "start:all:watch": "concurrently -k \"npm run build:client:watch\" \"dotnet watch run\"",
    "saw": "npm run start:all:watch"
  }
```

Finally, here is my overall project structure. How can I **re-serve the "wwwroot" folder** if I'm using dotnet run on **"localhost:5000"** after dotnet core detects that "wwwroot" (or server in "bin") has been re-built?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a proxy config for the Angular CLI to resolve the issue of hot module reloading both client and server with one command. A refresh is still required if only server code is changed. Now I'll just run client and server on different ports and use **"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"** to run client and **"dotnet watch run"** to run server.

[Create a proxy config for Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189533/how-to-run-angular-4-app-and-nodejs-api-on-same-port-4200-for-both-production-an)

For now **"Startup.cs"** will no longer serve the app bundle from the **"wwwroot"** folder (**UseDefaultFiles()** and **UseStaticFiles()** functions are removed).

Be sure to run **"dotnet restore"** if you've edited your ***.csproj** file before running the latest server code.